# Working with Named Regex Groups in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match regex groups over a series of lines and getting stumped. Data file has lines that look like this:

```
2014-03-01 08:19,47.799107662994,-75.876391553881,some comment,James,#tag
```

Here is my Ruby code:

```
regex = /(?<day>.*)\s(?<hour>\d*:\d*),(?<lat>.*),(?<long>.*),(?<entry>.*),(?<people>.*),#(?<tag>.*)/

f = File.open("/Users/USERNAME/path/to/file.txt", encoding: 'UTF-8')
lines = f.read
f.close
lines.each_line do |line|
  if line =~ /&/
    line.gsub!(/[&]/, 'and')
  end

  if regex =~ line
    puts line
  end
end
```

That works, **but** if I change that third to last to line to, for example `puts day`, then I get an error saying that is an undefined local variable. My understanding was that `=~` automatically defined those variables.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Ruby Rexexp docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html):

> When named capture groups are used with a literal regexp on the left-hand side of an expression and the =~ operator, the captured text is also assigned to local variables with corresponding names.

So it needs to be a *literal* regex that is used in order to create the local variables.

In your case you are using a variable to reference the regex, not a literal.

For example:

```
regex = /(?<day>.*)/
regex =~ 'whatever'
puts day
```

produces `` NameError: undefined local variable or method `day' for main:Object ``, but this

```
/(?<day>.*)/ =~ 'whatever'
puts day
```

prints `whatever`.

Comment: +1 I had no idea it created local variables. How terrifying and helpful.

Comment: @Phrogz “How terrifying” – I assume that’s why it’s restricted to literal regex in this way. At least the variables are then “local” in some sense in the source.

Comment: Word to the wise: it not only _creates_ local variables in this case, it **overwrites** existing local variables.

Comment: Oh! Perfect. I wasn't interpreting "literal" literally enough!

Answer (score 2):

You can only access value of the `named regex` through a `matchdata` object

```
regex = /(?<day>.*)\s(?<hour>\d*:\d*),(?<lat>.*),(?<long>.*),(?<entry>.*),(?<people>.*),#(?<tag>.*)/
line = "2014-03-01 08:19,47.799107662994,-75.876391553881,some comment,James,#tag"

matchdata = regex.match(line)

matchdata["day"] # => "2014-03-01"

so I would do as below instead:

if (matchdata = regex.match(line))
  puts matchdata["day"]
end
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you—I overlooked `matchdata`

Comment: You can only access match data through a `MatchData` instance, but you don't need to use `match` to get one. See my answer.

Comment: @Phrogz your answer is recommending a global variable that is always referencing the last regex and not a specific one

Comment: @bjhaid True. This is why I +1'd your answer. But in a single-threaded environment Ruby's Perl-inspired cryptic global variables are sometimes the easiest way to get certain work done.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
puts $~['day'] if regex =~ line
```

The (somewhat cryptic) `$~` global variable is a MatchData instance storing the results of the last regex match, and you can access your named captures in there.

<sub>*But the answer by @bjhaid is a better choice, saving the MatchData explicitly.*</sub>